# ArcGIS Runtime for wpf - PointDataSource mapTip

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

I have GraphicsLayer in my application and I use PointDataSource like itemsSource:

```
        trackEntryPointDataSource = new PointDataSource();
        trackEntryPointDataSource.DataSpatialReference = 
                                  new SpatialReference((int)CommonEpsgCodes.JTSKEN);
        trackEntryPointDataSource.XCoordinateBinding = 
                                  new System.Windows.Data.Binding("XJTSK");
        trackEntryPointDataSource.YCoordinateBinding = 
                                  new System.Windows.Data.Binding("YJTSK");
        SimpleRenderer srd = new SimpleRenderer();
        srd.Symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
        {
            Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow)
        };

        EntriesLyr.GraphicsSource = trackEntryPointDataSource;
        EntriesLyr.Renderer = srd;
```

Have someone any idea how to add MapTips to graphics symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphicsLayer class has a MapTip property.

A detailed example if found [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/index.html?esri.arcgis.client~esri.arcgis.client.graphicslayer_members.html)